# IU Unit in Virology

Tags: virology

In a paper recently I saw "Cell are infected with 50,000 IU of virus per 100ul well". I can not seem to find a defintion of this unit? Is it a functional unit or just a count? If someone is familiar with this definition please let me know.

It is a retrovirus. The thesis is here (page 18):
https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/bitstream/1807/98170/3/Mazzanti_Andrew_D_201911_MSc_thesis.pdf

Comment: IU usually stands for ["International Units"](https://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=9650). It can be functional of just a count. You'd have to search specifically for the meaning of IU for viruses to know what number of viruses per 100ul tat specifies.